# Failure to build any conda package on MAC OS

Tags: macos, conda, conda-build

When building any conda recipie on my macOS (High Sierra, version 10.13.6), I get the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libxml2.2.dylib   Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libarchive.13.dylib   

Reason: Incompatible library version: libarchive.dylib requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I have done the following:

- Downloaded and installed https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg.
- updated conda: `conda update conda`
- installed conda-build: `conda install conda-build`
- then tried building conda recipe: `conda install .`

I get this error when building any recipe, for the sake of example, here is the one i am trying:

```
package:
  name: cmake
  version: 3.2.3

source:
  fn: cmake-3.2.3.tar.gz [not win]
  url: http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.3.tar.gz [not win]

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:

  run:

about:
  home: http://www.cmake.org
  license:  BSD 3-clause
```

build.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

./bootstrap --prefix=$PREFIX

make
make install
```

Comment: Please provide a link to a recipe that fails for you and the command you're running to get that recipe, and the command you're running to build the recipe.

Comment: i have added an example recipe and commands i have used to build. FYI, This and other recipes work fine with these commands on win and linux.

Comment: Why are there no `build` or `run` requirements? It seems like you need at least `make` as a build dependency, and probably a C/C++ compiler (I'm not that familiar with CMake's build process). I'm not sure that this is the cause of the problem, but it is strange